# Angular 7 Custom Component registerOnChange is not a function

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have a zip code custom component that deals with an location dto (lat/long/city/state/zip).  When a user enters a zip it goes and retrieves all the relevant information and returns it to the form.  The form is reactive and has a form group associated with the zip code component (so the form group has lat/long/city/state/zip).

This works fine if I do NOT use a custom component.

When I move all the code to a custom component that I hope to use in my forms, I get an error saying that registerOnChange is not a function.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {
  Component,
  EventEmitter,
  forwardRef,
  Input,
  Output
} from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';
import { LocationDto } from '@model/shared/location-dto';
import { environment } from '@env/environment';

@Component({
  selector: 'foobar-zip-code',
  templateUrl: './zip-code.component.html',
  styles: [],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => ZipCodeComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class ZipCodeComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input()
  label: string;
  @Output()
  retrieved: EventEmitter<LocationDto> = new EventEmitter<LocationDto>();

  _location: LocationDto;
  _isDisabled = false;
  emptyLocation: LocationDto = new LocationDto();

  onChange: any = (location: LocationDto) => {};
  onTouched: any = () => {};

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this._location = new LocationDto();
  }

  get location() {
    return this._location ? this._location : new LocationDto();
  }

  set location(val) {
    this._location = val;
    this.onChange(this._location);
  }

  get isDisabled() {
    return this._isDisabled;
  }

  set isDisabled(val) {
    this._isDisabled = val;
  }

  public writeValue(value: LocationDto) {
    if (value !== undefined) {
      this.location = value;
      if (this.location.zipCode !== '') {
        this.lookupCity();
      }
    } else {
      this.location = new LocationDto();
    }
  }

  // has access to the function that informs the outside world about changes
  public registerOnChange(fn: (location: LocationDto) => void): void {
    this.onChange= fn;
  }

  public registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  lookupCity() {
    if (this.location.zipCode.length >= 5) {
      const zipCodeUrl = `${environment.resource.utilities}/ZipLookup?zip=${
        this.location.zipCode
      }`;
      this.http.get(zipCodeUrl).subscribe((response: LocationDto) => {
        Object.assign(this.location, response);
        this.onChange(this.location);
        this.retrieved.emit(this.location);
      });
    } else {
      this.retrieved.emit(this.emptyLocation);
    }
  }
}
```

The form that I am form is defined:

```
  fooBarForm= this.fb.group({
    location: this.fb.group({
      zipCode: [''],
      city: [''],
      state: [''],
      latitude: [0.0],
      longitude: [0.0]
    })
  });
```

and is called in the template with:

```
    <form [formGroup]="fooBarForm" novalidate>
    <foobar-zip-code
        label="Zip:"
        (retrieved)="zipCodeDetailsRetrieved($event)"
        formControlName="location"
      >
    </foobar-zip-code>
</form>
```

The Zip Code component is in a SharedModule that exports the component (and the CommonModule and ReactiveFormsModule).  The FooBarModule imports the SharedModule.  Since I am not getting any reference errors for the component itself, I assume that the export/import is setup properly.

Again, the error that I am getting is "TypeError: control.registerOnChange is not a function". I've been going in circles on this for a few days so any help or ideas would be incredibly helpful.  Thank you!

Comment: I don't see any obvious bug in your code, are you able to create a stackblitz for it? then we can try to fix it online

Comment: I went to create a stackblitz for it (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pncrf9) and the code actually worked fine which has made this all the more frustrating.  I'm wondering if there is some sort of other error happening and this registerOnChange error is coming up instead.

Comment: @JakeHova where you ever able to find the cause of this? I'm having the exact same issue with very similar code.

Comment: I never did find the cause of the specific issue I was having.  I ended up wiping out the node_modules folder and doing a fresh install then rebuilt the exact same component with a different name (exact same code just different name for the component) and it started working fine.  I don't think it was a bug with angular or any dependencies because the same code worked on stackblitz so I'm left to think that it had something to do with something caching something somewhere.  I wouldve taken more time to debug it but I had a release to get out.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this stubborn `registerOnChange is not a function`, which has stumped me for a long time until I finally figured it out.

In my case, the problem was that the object that `formControlName` referred to was a `FormGroup` (as in the code of this question):

```js
fooBarForm = this.fb.group({
  location: this.fb.group({    // <-- `group`
    zipCode: [''],
    city: [''],
    state: [''],
    latitude: [0.0],
    longitude: [0.0]
  })
});
```

As soon as I changed it into a `FormControl` with a plain object inside, it worked as expected:

```js
fooBarForm = this.fb.group({
  location: this.fb.control({  // <-- `control`
    zipCode: '',
    city: '',
    state: '',
    latitude: 0.0,
    longitude: 0.0
  })
});
```